# Can you travel through the US if you have recently had a study visa denied?

Tags: visas

My son has a US B1-B2 visa, but was recently denied a study visa for the USA. He now needs to fly to the Dominican Republic, but has to stop over in the US to catch his connecting flight. Will he be allowed to go through the US?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on several things.  Was his B-1/B-2 visa cancelled?  What was the reason for the refusal of the study visa?

Answer (score 3):

If the B-1/B-2 visa was not cancelled, then your son was presumably not found to be inadmissible to the US.  If that is true, then he is authorized "to go through the US."  Be careful, though.  An immigration officer could still refuse entry.  It would be safer to arrange travel through a different country.

It is also possible that he *was* found inadmissible and the consulate neglected to cancel the B visa because of an oversight or other administrative error.  It is therefore important to look at the refusal notice.  It will explain why the visa was refused.

Once you know the reason for the refusal, if you are not certain of the implications of that reason for future travel to the US, you can return and ask a new question or edit this one.